# Cannot connect jdbc to sql server 2008 r2

Tags: database, jdbc, database-connection, sql-server-2008r2-express, sqljdbc

I am using sql server 2008 r2 sql express.
I usually connect to my sql like this:
[image]

Now I want to connect to sql server 2008 r2 from my eclipse.

I searched google and I found that I have to download a jar file and I did and I added it to my project in eclipse.

my code is

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                    + "databaseName=DATABASE;user=User-PC\\User;password=;";
```

To be honest: I don't know if i should put `localhost` or `sqlexpress` and I don't know the password because as I should you in the image or I just use it empty.

the exception is :

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I enable TCP/IP in my sql configuration

please help me

Comment: are you using the root user?

Comment: yes, ................

Comment: `I have read that the root user can't can't be used in JDBC` so first you have to create a new `Login` in your sql server, then create new `User`. after that , please try to connect again and tell me what happened.

Comment: I created a new login with new user but when I tried to connect my server to that new user , I got authentication error

Comment: you have to choose sql authentication

Comment: I already did , and I give the user privilages and roles to the database .

Comment: did u assign the user with that login?

Comment: what? i didn't do that. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

when you create a new user , you have to set the login of that user, check the image please and press on the colored button, and select your login.

after that , change your string url connection to this:

```
Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_NAME);
            String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + DB_SERVER
                    + ";databaseName=" + DB_NAME + ";user=" + DB_USER
                    + ";password=" + DB_PASSWORD;
```

Comment: would you wait please, i am trying it